# how to do ng-model the right way to choose colors?

Tags: angularjs

Use case 1

1. I choose color from button = preview's color changes
2. I choose color from color picker works as well the preview changes
3. If i go to step one again the preview won't changes
4. it will only happen if i go to color picker then click the button

HTML

```
<!-- 1. Choose from the buttons listed -->
<div ng-repeat="color in colors">
   <button style="background-color: {{ color }}"
           ng-click="colorPicked(color)">
   </md-button>
</div>

<!-- 2. Choose from the input field -->
 <input type="text" name="fname" maxlength="7" ng-model="colorValue">

<!-- 3. Choose from color picker -->
 <input id="input-color" value="#f9ad17" type="color" name="color"
        ng-model="colorValue" ng-change="colorPicked(colorValue)"/>

<!-- Preview -->
<div style="background-color: {{ colorValue }}; width: 200px; height: 200px">
</div>
```

ColorController

```
$scope.colors = [
        '#d13438', '#ffb900', '#00cc6a', '#107c10', '#2258af', '#70a3ed',
        '#30363d', '#881798'];

$scope.colorPicked = function (color) {
    $scope.colorValue = color;

    }
}
```

UI

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what is the problem

Comment: remove `ng-change="colorPicked(colorValue)"` in your HTML element.

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes from this line:

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> <input id="input-color" value="#f9ad17" type="color" name="color"
>        ng-model="colorValue" ng-change="colorPicked(colorValue)"/>
> ```

You don't need to set the attributes `value` and `ng-change`. The initialisation of the value should be done in the controller:

```
$scope.colorValue = '#f9ad17';
```

Since the value is binded you don't need the ng-change.

Here is a complete working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vn0w76L/)

Answer (score 1):

Change as so:

```
<input id="input-color" ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶=̶"̶#̶f̶9̶a̶d̶1̶7̶"̶ type="color" name="color"
       ng-model="colorValue" ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶=̶"̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶P̶i̶c̶k̶e̶d̶(̶c̶o̶l̶o̶r̶V̶a̶l̶u̶e̶)̶"̶ />
```

```
$scope.colorValue = '#f9ad17';
```

## The DEMO

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.colorValue = '#f9ad17';
  $scope.colors = [
    '#d13438', '#ffb900', '#00cc6a', '#107c10', '#2258af', '#70a3ed',
    '#30363d', '#881798'
  ];
  $scope.colorPicked = function(color) {
    $scope.colorValue = color;
  }
})
```

```css
.color-button {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <!-- 1. Choose from the buttons listed -->
    <span  ng-repeat="color in colors">
      <button style="background-color: {{ color }}"
              class="color-button"
              ng-click="colorPicked(color)">
      </button>
    </span><br>

    <!-- 2. Choose from the input field -->
    <input type="text" name="fname" maxlength="7" ng-model="colorValue">

    <!-- 3. Choose from color picker -->
    <input id="input-color" type="color" name="color" ng-model="colorValue" />

    <!-- Preview -->
    <div style="background-color: {{ colorValue }}; width: 200px; height: 200px">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, don't use style and interpolate values as it may get overwritten. Instead use ng-style directive:

```
ng-style="{'background-color': colorValue}"
```

Second, ng-change directive is unnecessery on input-color